# Converting a list of tuples into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm new to run-length coding and need help. I've been given a run-length string of a series of integer followed by characters that include letters/characters.
For example, I have a string:

```
1-4c8k2)
```

And I need to convert it into:

```
-cccckkkkkkkk))
```

What I've done is convert the run-length string into a list of tuples:
`[('1','-'),('4','c'),('8','k'),('2','c')]`
And tried creating a function which would convert it into a string however I get a 
**TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'.**

```
def decode(lst):
    q = ''
    for count, character in lst:
        q += count * character
    return q
```

I'm trying to think of a way to improve space complexity instead of creating a new list of tuples and more so, trying to resolve this TypeError.

Comment: What version of python are you running?  This works for me in 3.5

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Strange.. I'm running 3.4.3

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that what has happened is you forgot to convert the counts into `ints`:

```
>>> 3 * 'a'
'aaa'
```

---

```
>>> '3' * 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

---

```
>>> int('3') * 'a'
'aaa'
```

Comment: Wow, that was really silly of me. Thanks heaps! I realized I had created my tuples as ('2',')') rather than (2,')').

Answer (score 0):

You try through this way :

```
lst = [('1','-'),('4','c'),('8','k'),('2','c')]
def decode(lst):
    q = ''
    for count, character in lst:
        q += int(count) * character
    return q

print(decode(lst))
```

Output :

```
-cccckkkkkkkkcc
```

Check this code [here](https://repl.it/MWQF/1)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed since I had formatted my list of integers as strings so this rectified the issue